# Swift: vertically align subviews in center of parent view in dynamic way? Use manual calculation? Better to use SKSpriteNodes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, sprite-kit

Other posts discuss how to align subviews to the center of their parent. What about the following:

- ParentView (100x300)
- ChildA (100x100)
- ChildB (100x100)
- ChildC (100x100)

ChildA, ChildB, and ChildC can get dynamically added or removed from ParentView. Upon adding/removing, the visible subviews should readjust to align vertically within ParentView. For instance, if only ChildA is visible, then it should be centered inside of ParentView. But if all three are visible, then each should occupy one-third of the vertical space of ParentView.

Is manual calculation the best way to achieve this programmatically? If so, what advantage is there to creating this with UIView as opposed to SpriteKit?

Comment: SKSpriteNodes are absolutely unrelated here. Unfortunately there is no autolayout in SpriteKit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to handle this would be to use auto layout and set up four "spacer" views - one between A, B, and C and one on either side of A and C between the parent. Set the spacers all equal to each other.

Also have the spacer views' constant set to zero if the attached view is not present.